# Ковертор переменной времени в Unix timestamp средствами batch

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Есть следующие переменные:

```
set mytime=20161212192749
set myY=%mytime:~0,4%
set myM=%mytime:~4,2%
set myD=%mytime:~6,2%
set myH=%mytime:~8,2%
set myMi=%mytime:~10,2%
set myS=%mytime:~12,2%
```

Как средствами batch файла получить переменную %myunixtime% - время в виде Unix timestamp:

```
1481570869
```

Comment: Очень сложно - там куча вычислений... Нет вариантов перейти на другой язык? На тот же powershell?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, устроит вариант CLI утилиты если таковая существует для конвертации времени (переменной) в unix timestamp.

Comment: Существует, я ее вам уже написал :)

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, А на VBS можно реализовать с выводом результата в консоль? unixtimestamp.vbs 20161212192749  результат выполнения текст 1481570869 ?

Comment: Можно. Реализуйте. Разрешаю! :)

Answer (score 1):

Если есть powershell - то можно сделать вот так:

```
for /F %%i in ('powershell "((new-object system.datetime %myY%,%myM%,%myD%,%myH%,%myMi%,%myS%) - (new-object system.datetime 1970,1,1)).TotalSeconds"') do (
  set myUnixTime=%%i
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто для истории реализация на PHP. Пример не претендует на оптимальное решение. Тестировалось на версии PHP-5.2.17.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set mytime=20161212192749
set myY=%mytime:~0,4%
set myM=%mytime:~4,2%
set myD=%mytime:~6,2%
set myH=%mytime:~8,2%
set myMi=%mytime:~10,2%
set myS=%mytime:~12,2%

for /f "delims==" %%i in (' echo "" ^| php.exe -R "echo date('U', strtotime('%myY%-%myM%-%myD% %myH%:%myMi%:%myS%'));" ') do set "myunixtime=%%i"

echo %myunixtime%
```

**add: поправка на временную зону**

```
for /f "delims==" %%i in (' echo "" ^| php.exe -R "echo date('U', strtotime('%myY%-%myM%-%myD% %myH%:%myMi%:%myS%')) + date('Z');" ') do set "myunixtime=%%i"
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже давал ответ на похожий вопрос. Думаю, пригодится кому-нибудь функция для batch-файлов, конвертирующая время из формата dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS во время в формате UTC.
Примечание: перед значением входного параметра следует поставить знак двойных кавычек "

Пример вывода текущего времени: **call:2UTC "%date% %time%**

```
call:2UTC "%date% %time%
@set timestamp=%utc%
@echo %timestamp% 
@goto end

:2UTC    - Function start. Parameter format="dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS.......
@REM - output variable name = %utc%. Second's ciphers can be skipped. Ex.:   "dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM

@set ts=%1
@set ts=%ts:~1%
@set /a "yy=10000%ts:~6,4% %% 10000, mm=100%ts:~3,2% %% 100, dd=100%ts:~0,2% %% 100, H=%ts:~11,2%"
@set /a "M=100%ts:~14,2% %%100, S=100%ts:~17,2% %%100"
@set /a z=(14-mm)/12, y=yy-z, utc=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400+(153*(mm+12*z-3)+2)/5+dd-719469, utc=utc*86400+H*3600+M*60+S
@goto end

:end
```